# SQL select the max value of a sum

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm new to the forum and SQL and have really appreciated all the information.  I couldn't find a solution that works for me already addressed so thought I'd give this a shot here.  Operating in Snowflake. My dataset looks like this (apologies for troublesome formatting):

```
PO  | DIV | PROD |  QTY |   CUST
123 | 1  | x |  10 |    Sonic
234 |   1 | x   | 9 |   Sonic
345 | 1 |   x | 8   | McD
456 | 1 | x | 10    | Wendy's
```

I would like to sum on QTY by DIV, PROD, and CUST. Once I have those summed up quantities, I would like to take the largest SUM(QTY) by DIV and PROD but retain the CUST field.  Thus the answer from the above would look like this:

```
1 | x | 19| Sonic
```

Just note, I obviously have a much larger database so that i would have all the unique product/division combinations with the max(sum()) listed, about 600K rows.

The code I have here gets me to the point where I have the sum(QTY) but now I need to pull the row with the max sum(QTY) while retaining the CUST field.  Can you help?  I found some info on greatest-n-per-group but wasn't sure if that's what I should be using and how

```
SELECT DIV, PROD, CUST, SUM(QTY) as QTY
from table
GROUP BY 
    DIV,
    PROD,
    CUST
Order by 
    DIV,
    PROD
```

EDIT:
Jay's CTE approach worked for me but I forgot to mention that I'd like to create a table out of this.  CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE didn't work with the CTE.  Any ways to create a table using the CTE approach, or a different approach?

Thanks!

Comment: SQL Server, MySQL or other Server?

Comment: other but based on SQL as far as I know. It's Snowflake

Comment: Note SO (and the other StackExchange sites) isn't a forum but a Q&A site. Clarifications should be edited into the original question, not posted as comments. See the site help (links are various places on the page, including the SE menu, which opens from the SE icon in the upper right) for more info, including how to format questions and answers.

Comment: Using Jay's CTE approach, you can run the query and then save the results to a table in Snowflake in a subsequent step:

`CREATE TABLE <new_table> AS 
select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id()))`

Answer (score 3):

**MYSQL**

```
SELECT `DIV`, PROD, CUST,QTY from 
(
SELECT `DIV`, PROD, CUST, SUM(QTY) as QTY from 
table1 
GROUP BY `DIV`, PROD, CUST Order by `DIV`, PROD
) AS T
WHERE QTY=(SELECT MAX(QTY) FROM (SELECT `DIV`, PROD, CUST, SUM(QTY) as QTY from 
table1 
GROUP BY `DIV`, PROD, CUST Order by `DIV`, PROD) AS T)
```

OR

```
SELECT `DIV`, PROD, CUST,QTY from 
(
SELECT `DIV`, PROD, CUST, SUM(QTY) as QTY from 
table1 
GROUP BY `DIV`, PROD, CUST Order by `DIV`, PROD
) AS T ORDER BY QTY DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f945c2b/19

**SQL SERVER**

Using CTE

```
WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT DIV, PROD, CUST, SUM(QTY) as QTY,
 DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DIV, PROD ORDER BY SUM(QTY) DESC) AS Rank
 FROM 
 table1 
 GROUP BY DIV, PROD, CUST
)
SELECT DIV, PROD, CUST,QTY FROM CTE
WHERE Rank=1
ORDER BY DIV, PROD
```

Using Nested Query

```
SELECT DIV, 
       PROD, 
       CUST,
       QTY 
FROM ( 
      SELECT DIV, PROD, CUST, SUM(QTY) as QTY, 
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DIV, PROD ORDER BY SUM(QTY) DESC) AS Rank
      FROM table1 
      GROUP BY DIV, PROD, CUST )AS T1 
 WHERE Rank=1 ORDER BY DIV, PROD;
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/22001/11

Comment: Thanks, Jay!  When I run this I get an error: SQL compilation error: [T.DIV] is not a valid group by expression

Comment: Snowflake supports windowing functions (as shown in the `dense_rank()` example)

Comment: Jay when I ran your code I only got one line, I'm guessing it's the max(QTY) observation across all observations.  What I'm looking for is to get the max but grouped by DIV and PROD, resulting in 10 rows if I have 10 unique DIV/PROD combinations, for example

Comment: `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DIV, PROD ORDER BY SUM(QTY) DESC) AS Rank`  Try `DENSE_RANK()` With Partition as Above

Comment: The DENSE_RANK() update helped a bunch.  Looks like that got me to the answer.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome!! @DavidDance

Comment: @Jay Shankar Gupta One other thing I wanted to do is create a table at the end of this.  Looks like I can't use CREATE TABLE at the beginning with the CTE.  Is there are workaround?

Comment: `SELECT DIV, PROD, CUST,QTY  INTO new_table
From
(
  SELECT DIV, PROD, CUST, SUM(QTY) as QTY,
 DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(QTY) DESC) AS Rank 
 FROM 
 table1 
 GROUP BY DIV, PROD, CUST
)AS T1
WHERE Rank=1
ORDER BY DIV, PROD;` You can use Nested query

Answer (score 0):

You could filter your aggregate `sum(qty)` via `having` clause

```
select 
       DIV, PROD, CUST, SUM(QTY) as QTY 
from table
group by DIV, PROD, CUST
having sum(QTY) = ( select max(QTY) from (
                    select sum(QTY) as QTY from table
                    group by DIV, PROD, CUST)a)
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh, something in that may not be supported in Snowflake as I get an error: "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated"

Answer (score 0):

Try this in MySQL:

```
SELECT A.`DIV`, A.PROD, IF(A.`DIV`=0,'NAN',A.AGG_QTY/A.`DIV`) QTY, A.CUST
FROM (SELECT `DIV`, PROD, CUST, SUM(QTY) AGG_QTY
      FROM `TABLE` 
      GROUP BY `DIV`, PROD, CUST
      ORDER BY SUM(QTY) DESC
      LIMIT 1) A;
```

See it run on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4122cc/2)

Answer (score -1):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectQuery = "SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '"+ username.Text + "' AND `password` = '" + password.Text +"';";
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectQuery, DBConnect);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);
    if (table.Rows.Count <= 0)
    {
        // label_Message.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        // label_Message.Text = "Username Or Password Are Invalid";
        //timer1.Start();
        MessageBox.Show("Username Or Password Are Invalid");
    }
    else
    {
        //  panel1.Height = 0;
        //  label_Message.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        //  label_Message.Text = "Login Successfully";
        //   timer1.Start();
        MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully");
        admin1 admin1 = new admin1();
        admin1.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    table.Clear();
}
```

Comment: MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From login where username='" + txtid.Text + "' and password='" + txtpass.Text + "'", connection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {

                this.Hide();
                Form2 ms = new Form2();
                ms.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please check your id and password");
            }
        }

Comment: SELECT SUM(stock) as jumlahstock FROM barang 

Source: http://dwirandyherdinanto.blogspot.co.id/2014/02/penggunaan-sum-min-max-count-avg-di-sql.html